# Lucene inverted file schema diagram

Tags: lucene, schema

Looking for an actual visual artifact of the schema for Lucene's inverted store.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [Lucene index file format](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/fileformats.html) can help you.